# Using both Drupal Core Contact Form and contributed Webform module

Tags: forms, webforms

I have a Drupal 8 site already utilizing core Contact Form. However, we now need a more complex form and thinking about installing a contributed module: Webform (https://www.drupal.org/project/webform).

My concern is that having both Contact form and Webform enabled, will there be an issue like one impacting the other?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is fine to use both. If you are not using the Contact Storage module, it should be very easy to convert your contact forms to webforms.

Comment: Thank you @jrockowtz.